# AndEngine draw line top and bottom of the screen

Tags: android, andengine

I am using AndEngine, I want to draw a line in the top as a roof of my screen .. and one in the bottom as a ground.

How to get their coordinates?

```
                final Line line = new Line(StartX, StartY, lastX,
                        lastY, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

[image]

A picture demonstrating what I mean. The black lines are the one I want, the red dots are the coordinations I need to draw the black lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it, the roof is

```
                line1 = new Line(0, 0, width,
                        0, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

and the ground

```
                line1 = new Line(0, width, height,
                        width, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

by using ur screen ratios.

Comment: the ground line should actually be :  new Line(0, height, width, height, getVertexBufferObjectManager());